Can someone tell me what this curve is called?
I am rotating an object with the axis of rotation is not in the center of gravity.
At the same point I am rotating the axis of rotation on a circle by the same angle.
The center of mass of the object moves along a certain curve (red crosses).
Can someone tell me what this curve is called?


I believe that's a Limaçon.

It appears similar to a  limaçon:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on
These come in several varieties, but you can make one with the inner loop by something like $r= \frac{1}{2} + \cos \theta$ in polar coordinates.  Suitably rotated, that closely resembles your curve.

"limaçon" is a french word ("snail" in English) and your curve is the "limaçon de Pascal).
